# Meaning of "it will take for granted that you always took it for granted"

Tags: meaning, pronouns, ambiguity, it-its-itself

I am reading William Empson's "Seven Types of Ambiguity", and I have difficulty with the following passage, especially with the part in bold and the preceding sentences.

> A single word,
> dropped where it comes most easily, without being stressed, and
> as if to fill out the sentence, may signal
> to the reader what he is
> meant to be taking
> for granted;
> if it is already
> in his mind the
> word will seem natural enough and will not act as an unnecessary
> signal. **Once it has gained
> its point, on further readings,
> it will
> take for granted that you always took it for granted**; only very
> delicate people are as tactful in this matter as the printed page.
> Nearly all statements assume in this way that you know something but not everything about the matter in hand, and would
> tell you something different if you knew more; but printed
> commonly differ from spoken
> ones in being intended for a
> greater variety of people, and poetical from prosaic ones in
> imposing the system of habits they imply more firmly or more
> quickly.

What does it mean, *"it will take for granted that you always took it for granted"*? Does the first *"it"* refer to *"the word"*? If yes, how can a word take something for granted?

Comment: I think he's saying that once you learn something, in the future it seems obvious and you can't even remember what it was like you didn't understand it. For example, try to remember what it was like to look at a book before you learned how to read (you can get a little idea of this by looking at a book in a different language, especially one with a different alphabet).

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, but the syntax of the phrase in bold is still obscure to me. To bring it closer to your explanation, I may try to replace _"it will take for granted"_ with _"you will take for granted"_, but I still feel like the real meaning slips away from me. For me the sentence doesn't seem to convey clearly the idea you have described.

Comment: He's speaking in flowery language, ascribing the reader's understanding to the word itself.

Comment: I suggest he's speaking not simply in flowery, but in clearly pretentious language. At best, 'it will take for granted that you always took it for granted' will always be more questionable than clear.